# Wildcard file ignore is not working in .talismanrc

Tags: git, pre-commit, talisman

I have these files in project root

- test.sql and test1.sql
- .talismanrc

```
fileignoreconfig:
- filename: '*.sql'
  checksum: 29a138ee50018bdc968f352d2a69fa09e17de38fcc400630bb04dd7019e768be
# - filename: abc.sql
#   checksum: e12b607678a6b1821eca6e49f36588d8e89f8e6ed0f8a6abc6ef53b394bdc06b
# - filename: abc1.sql
#   checksum: cdca6d4d3d4c094fbdaeae9b6202fcf39be192454616e1e7d5b6fc2c60d25887
```

- .pre-commit-config

```
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/thoughtworks/talisman
    rev: v1.2.0
    hooks:
    # either `commit` or `push` support
    -   id: talisman-commit
    # -   id: talisman-push
```

I am trying to write ignore rule for `.sql` file so that I don't need multiple entries in `.talismanrc`.
This is how I generated checksum for `'*.sql'` 
`talisman --checksum="*.sql"` 
When I try with two different rules it's working but wildcard rule is not working.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing `ignore_detectors`. After generating `checksum` using `talisman --checksum="*.sql"` I got the following

```
fileignoreconfig:
- filename: '*.sql'
  checksum: 29a148ff50018bdc968f352d2a69fa09e17de38fcc400630bb04dd7019e768be
```

and I added `ignore_detectors`.
The final `.talismanrc` files look like this

```
fileignoreconfig:
- filename: '*.sql'
  checksum: 29a138ee50018bdc968f352d2a69fa09e17de38fcc400630bb04dd7019e768be
  ignore_detectors: [filename]
```